# Why judgement during Josiah's reign?

Tags: judgement, zephaniah, exile, judah, josiah

Why does God send judgment Words during the reign of Josiah through Zephaniah, seeing that he was bringing about reformations?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Question here need a specific Bible passage to consider.

Comment: What Bible text are you considering?

Answer (score 1):

You needed to give references. The "why?" question can be answered with help from the similar prophecy of Huldah in 2 Kings ch22 vv14-22.

The short answer in her case is that she was only confirming a verdict of judgement against the kingdom which had been made earlier, and was irrevocable. The Lord had announced this verdict "by his servants the prophets" in the time of Manasseh two reigns previously (2 kings ch21 vv10-15); "Behold, I am bringing upon Jerusalem and upon Judah such evil that the ears of everyone who hears of it will tingle... because they have done what is evil in my sight and have provoked me to anger, since the day their fathers came out of Egypt" (RSV).

Therefore Josiah's repentance was effective only in protecting himself and in delaying the judgment to the time after his death. Ultimately, Huldah's prophecy is a forewarning of the fall of Jerusalem at the hands of Nebuchadnezzar, in the reign of one of the sons of Josiah. You will notice that the king's sons are included in the criticism of Zephaniah ch1 v8, which in itself is not a good omen for the future.

It's all explained in Huldah's own words. "I will bring evil upon this place and upon its inhabitants" (v16). But as to the king of Judah himself "Because your heart was penitent... I will gather you to your fathers... and your eyes shall not see all the evil which I will bring upon this place" (v20)

In short, the words of judgment are given during Josiah's reign, but the act of judgment itself is in a later reign, and the same may be said of the warnings of Zephaniah.

Answer (score 0):

:) I often warn our nation of the coming judgment. What is the abomination? Preborn child genocide. Life begins at conception. When a nation legalizes child sacrifice they have crossed God's blood red line. This is a national judgment not a judgment against the individual. While David committed murder and lost his son, not everyone who murders and repents receives the consequence now as King Manasseh who sacrificed his son thru a horrible death did not. I wondered about God's view of abortion and why the horrific suffering of Revelation when the world is conquered.

There is only one time in the Old Testament that states "And the LORD would not forgive." It is in 2 Kings 24:3 & 4. The nation of Judah was not forgiven but King Manasseh was forgiven. The biblical consequence of nationally legalized child sacrifice is invasion and conquest. However, a reprieve is given with overturning the law but it is a suspended sentence. God has His own timeline. Notice in 2 Chronicles 33 "2 He [Manasseh] did evil in the sight of the Lord according to the abominations of the nations whom the Lord dispossessed before the sons of Israel." What was the sin of the Amorite that was not completed when Abraham was promised the land of Canaan in Genesis 15:16? Child sacrifice.

Thus, the fulfillment of the judgment does come, but after a great revival under Josiah. I am hoping there will be a great worldwide revival before the Great Tribulation, but the nation of Israel which never repented was dispersed, so maybe the nations that have overturned their abomination laws will survive. Not sure about those that do not.

May want to look into Artificial Intelligence growth, ChatGPT. Those who understand it are petrified. It may be how the anti-Messiah comes into power. There are very few nations in which pre-born child sacrifice is not legalized.

Comment: What of other times when the LORD will not forgive such as Deut 29:20, Josh 24:19, Ex 23:21 ??

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question refer to the whole book of Zephaniah. I agree with Stephen's answer that the Lord declared His verdict of judgment that was irrevocable. It can be seen in chapter 1, the affirming tone in the narrative.

In the book, there is no asking of reformation, no further postponement of the decree of the Lord. Judah had to await their judgment, in the Day of the Lord. Through the prophesy of Zephaniah, the Lord summoned Judah to repent, before the decree took effect, so that **some of them** could be saved, who became the **remnant**, exile to Babylon.

> 1 Gather together, gather yourselves together, you shameful nation,
>
> 2 **before the decree takes effect** and that day passes like windblown chaff,
> before the Lord’s fierce anger comes upon you,
> before the day of the Lord’s wrath comes upon you.
>
> 3 Seek the Lord, all you humble of the land, you who do what he commands.
> Seek righteousness, seek humility; **perhaps you will be sheltered
> on the day of the Lord’s anger.** (Zephaniah 2:1-3)

Therefore the purpose of Zephaniah's prophesy was to save the remnant of Israel, who later returned from exile to restore the nation. But the kingdom will be forever gone.

Answer (score 0):

Zephaniah was probably writing prior to the reforms that Josiah initiated. Josiah began his reign when he was still a boy, at the age of eight, and made no such reforms for another 18 years, according to 2 Kings 22:

> Josi′ah was eight years old when he began to reign, and he reigned
> thirty-one years in Jerusalem. ...In the eighteenth year of King
> Josi′ah, the king sent Shaphan the son of Azali′ah, son of Meshul′lam,
> the secretary, to the house of the Lord... 8 And Hilki′ah the high
> priest said to Shaphan the secretary, “I have found the book of the
> law in the house of the Lord.” ...And Shaphan read it before the king.
> 11 And when the king heard the words of the book of the law, he rent
> his clothes.

This begins the period of Josiah's campaign against non-Israelite religious influence. Before this time, Judah was under strong Assyrian sway during King Manasseh's reign, which provoked denunciations from prophets such as Jeremiah:

> I will appoint over them four kinds of destroyers, says the Lord: the
> sword to slay, the dogs to tear, and the birds of the air and the
> beasts of the earth to devour and destroy. 4 And I will make them a
> horror to all the kingdoms of the earth because of what Manas′seh the
> son of Hezeki′ah, king of Judah, did in Jerusalem. (Jer. 15)

It must have been in this spirit that Zephaniah made his dire prophecies in the first chapter of his book. Thus, an introduction to *Zephaniah* in the [New American Bible](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/zephaniah/0) reads:

> The protest against the worship of false gods and the condemnation of
> foreign practices (1:8–9) may indicate that Zephaniah spoke during the
> height of Assyrian influence in the early years of Josiah’s reign,
> before Josiah launched the religious reforms praised by Israel’s
> historians (2 Kgs 22:1–23:30).

**So the OP is probably mistaken when it presumes that Josiah had already begun his reforms when this prophecy was issued. Zephaniah prophesied against policies originally instituted by King Manasseh, which persisted during the first decades of Josiah's reign.**